# Using the_excerpt() on a page

Tags: php, pages, excerpt

I've been trying to utilize the PHP excerpt function to call from her recent blog post to post on a [main landing page](http://www.chazsouthard.com/art/) without avail. Any thoughts?

```
<div id="home_news" class="prefix_9 grid_3">
    <div id="newsbox" style="display: block;">
        <div id="news">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <div id="news_content">Welcome to the... .check back shortly for a new selection of oil paintings, latest prints and greeting cards</a>. 

<?php 
$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=blog&posts_per_page=1'); 

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    $do_not_duplicate = $post->505;
    the_excerpt();

endwhile; ?> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this was far from clear in the OP at first, I think this might be a good solution. Just make a shortcode to place the excerpt in the body. (This is a bad idea if you want this on *every page*. This is a good idea if you want it once in a while on some pages in the body.)

Here's code to put in your functions.php:

```
function the_excerpt_shortcode() {
    return get_the_excerpt();
}
add_shortcode( 'the_excerpt', 'the_excerpt_shortcode' );
```

Once you have the, just put this in your page body:

```
[the_excerpt]
```

And you're good to go.

If you're using Twenty Ten, Twenty Eleven, or some other theme that hooks to the excerpt_more filter, you may have to modify that short code to strip an auto-generated "Continue Reading..." link, but for many themes that's unnecessary. Consider this a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

`the_excerpt()` won't work on a landing page.  It must be used inside the post [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in order to function.

Inside the loop, WordPress populates a global `$post` variable with information about the current post.  Then, various [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags) reference that global variable and output content.

---

**Based on your edits above ...**

You *almost* have your loop structured correctly.  But instead, you'll need to:

1. Create your own page query to grab the latest post
2. Display the post
3. Restore the original query

The code below should do what you need:

```
<div id="home_news" class="prefix_9 grid_3">
    <div id="newsbox" style="display: block;">
        <div id="news">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <div id="news_content">Welcome to the... .check back shortly for a new selection of oil paintings, latest prints and greeting cards</a>. 

<?php 
// Create a new query and grab the latest post from the "blog" category
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=blog&posts_per_page=1' ); 

// If we have a post, populate the necessary global variables and run the loop
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    // Echo the post excerpt on the page
    the_excerpt();

endwhile; endif;

// Reset the main loop data so global variables have the right values
wp_reset_postdata();
?> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to add the loop within a page? I've been playing around with it… No luck yet.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the [multiple loops examples in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_2).

Comment: I edited my question because I couldn't get the markdown format to appear in my comment. does the post->ID need to be specified?  Is the ID a global named variable?

Comment: After you call `the_post()` you populate a global `$post` variable that has an `ID` member.

Comment: okay–so I replaced the ID  with a number of the post?

Comment: How do I find the numerical ID of the specific page?

Comment: `get_the_ID()` returns the numerical ID of the current post when used in the loop.

Comment: I added in the numerical value. No luck. Any other ideas? Any recommendations on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: See my edits. Inside the loop (where I have `the_excerpt()`) you can run any of the standard template tags you need.  If you need the numeric ID, run `get_the_ID()` to return it or `the_ID()` to `echo` it.  If you need the title, use `get_the_title()` like normal.

Comment: Theoretically the code above should validate and work. I have a category titled 'blog'.  I'm a little afraid to mess with any of the edits. I've left the code as is and inputted into the page and it still doesn't render.  Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: Looking at your site, it seems the PHP isn't parsing ... so my question is *where* are you putting this code?

Comment: I'm applying the code within a page. The HTML section.

Comment: OK, that's why it won't work.  PHP code is stripped out in the HTML/Visual editor in WordPress.  You need to either add this code to the [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) used by the landing page directly or add a [PHP execution plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/) to WordPress so inline PHP runs.

Comment: Got it. Almost there. Except that I'm now entering another error… Thoughts? http://www.chazsouthard.com/art/

Comment: Typo in my code (now fixed above). Should be `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: It is working now–but it is conflicting with the CSS. Is there a way to limit the amount of characters in the excerpt?  I think that is what is throwing off the code.

Comment: Read up on [Controlling excerpt length using filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters).

Comment: Finally figured it out. Thanks for staying with me through the confusion.  Is there a way to properly post a thumbnail inside  the excerpt?

Comment: No ... but that's not to say you can't post a thumbnail + an excerpt in a template.  But that's a separate question, so you should really open a new question ...